# Identity Server 3 Reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, identityserver3

I am having problems with Identity Server 3 and load balancers.

The issue is solved for Identity Server 4 ([here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/708)), but I need a similar solution for Identity Server 3.

Is there something?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Terminating SSL](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/deployment.html) section under the deployment docs...

There are more details for those two settings in the docs for: [IdentityServerOptions](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityServerOptions.html)

**RequireSsl**

> Indicates if SSL is required for IdentityServer. Defaults to true

**PublicOrigin**

> By default, IdentityServer uses the host, protocol, and port from the
> HTTP request when creating links. This might not be accurate in
> reverse proxy or load-balancing situations. You can override the
> origin used for link generation using this property.

Comment: We deployed app behind trafeik reverse proxy and we implemented the ADFS integration with the identity server. When the callback happens after getting authenticated,we got Http 405 POST not supported error. We solved it by setting the PublicOrigin